# gmail api token expired how to get new one?

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have just implemented Gmail OAuth service and I am able to send emails, but after some time it expires it should, I am just wondering how do I renew it automatically ?

here. is my code:

```
func OAuthGmailService() {
    config := oauth2.Config{
       ClientID:     "XXXXXX",
       ClientSecret: "XXXXXX",
       Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
       RedirectURL:  "http://127.0.0.1",
    }
 
    token := oauth2.Token{
       AccessToken:  "XXXXXX",
       RefreshToken: "XXXXXX",
       TokenType:    "Bearer",
       Expiry: time.Now(),
    }
    

    var tokenSource = config.TokenSource(context.Background(), &token)
 
    srv, err := gmail.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithTokenSource(tokenSource))
    if err != nil {
       log.Printf("Unable to retrieve Gmail client: %v", err)
    }
 
    GmailService = srv
    if GmailService != nil {
       fmt.Println("Email service is initialized \n")
    }

 }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question. Contact the vendor directly for assistance. We can't help with questions about your specific account on that site.

Comment: Voting reopen as it has nothing to do with customer service. However it does have everything to do with how to use Google Oauth with the Go programming language and understanding how Oauth2 works with a refresh token.    Access tokens expire after one hour you should use the refresh token to request a new access token when you need. one.  I cant help you do this in go but this might help https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: You could try and dig around in the [Google apis go client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client) for documentation that will help you understand how to do this in go.

Answer (score 1):

#### First look for the local token

In the quick start documentation:

> https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go

In the `getClient` function:

```golang
func getClient(config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        tokFile := "token.json"
        tok, err := tokenFromFile(tokFile) // First seeking local token
        if err != nil {
                tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
                saveToken(tokFile, tok)
        }
        return config.Client(context.Background(), tok)
}
```

This should be sufficient to use the refresh token and note require a subsequent login.

I can't tell by your code if this logic is in your program.

If not, check out:

> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration

For more information about how your refresh token may be expiring, for instance it could be:

> The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit old, but since I was also searching a similar issue I'm answering here too.

You need to add the functionality of automatically creating the Access token based on the quickstart of Gmail API, just like the answer of *@iansedano* above.

After that, use the option `option.WithHTTPClient(client)` instead of WithTokenSource

You can check my research here: [Gmail API with Go and gmail.NewService invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153701/gmail-api-with-go-and-gmail-newservice-invalid-memory-address-or-nil-pointer-der/71156672)