# Gmail API with Go and gmail.NewService invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, gmail-api

I have an issue with the new NewService functionality of gmail api. If I use the deprecated gmail.New() everything works.
With NewService() I get `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

My implementation is the following

```
type MailData struct {
    To      string
    Name    string
    Subject string
    Content template.HTML
}    

func doSend(msg *gmail.Message, srv *gmail.Service) error {
    _, err := srv.Users.Messages.Send("me", msg).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func ComposeMessage(m models.MailData) *gmail.Message {

    var gmailMessage gmail.Message

    from := mail.Address{Name: "Sender", Address: os.Getenv("MAIL_FROM")}
    replyTo := os.Getenv("MAIL_REPLYTO")
    to := mail.Address{Name: m.Name, Address: m.To}

    header := make(map[string]string)
    header["From"] = from.String()
    header["Reply-To"] = replyTo
    header["To"] = to.String()
    header["Subject"] = m.Subject
    header["MIME-Version"] = "1.0"
    header["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\""
    header["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "base64"

    var msg string
    for k, v := range header {
        msg += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
    }
    msg += "\r\n" + string(m.Content)

    gmailMessage.Raw = base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(msg))
    return &gmailMessage
}
```

Using the old gmail.New() works, but it points out that the function is deprecated, so I need to change it to the new gmail.NewService. Though implementing it like below it doesn't work

```
func sendGMail(m models.MailData) error {
    credentials := "../gmail_credentials.json"

    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := gmail.NewService(
        ctx,
        option.WithCredentialsFile(credentials),
        option.WithScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("unable to retrieve gmail client: %s", err))
    }

    // Create message
    gMessage := ComposeMessage(m)

    if err := doSend(gMessage, srv); err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("could not send mail: %s", err))
    }
    fmt.Println("Email sent")

    return nil
}
```

Edit: the error I get is

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x9a161b]

goroutine 13 [running]:
golang.org/x/oauth2/authhandler.authHandlerSource.Token({{0xc2fb30, 0xc00003c108}, 0xc0002a1340, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}})
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8/authhandler/authhandler.go:48 +0x5b
golang.org/x/oauth2.(*reuseTokenSource).Token(0xc00011d1e0)
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8/oauth2.go:304 +0xd5
golang.org/x/oauth2.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc00011d220, 0xc000124600)
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8/transport.go:45 +0xa7
net/http.send(0xc000124600, {0xc1d200, 0xc00011d220}, {0xb13600, 0xc000263701, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:252 +0x5d8
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc000483200, 0xc000124600, {0xc0002637f8, 0x4f49b5, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:176 +0x9b
net/http.(*Client).do(0xc000483200, 0xc000124600)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:725 +0x908
net/http.(*Client).Do(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:593
google.golang.org/api/internal/gensupport.SendRequest({0x0, 0x0}, 0xb33a63, 0xc000124600)
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/api@v0.30.0/internal/gensupport/send.go:43 +0xb8
google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1.(*UsersMessagesSendCall).doRequest(0xc000263e10, {0xb2b9fa, 0x4})
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/api@v0.30.0/gmail/v1/gmail-gen.go:6836 +0xa05
google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1.(*UsersMessagesSendCall).Do(0xc000263e10, {0x0, 0x1b, 0xb4e56a})
        /home/joss/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/api@v0.30.0/gmail/v1/gmail-gen.go:6848 +0x78
github.com/user/mailprj/internal.doSend(0xc0000f6180, 0x12)
        /home/joss/user/mailprj/internal/gmail-api.go:159 +0xa5
github.com/user/mailprj/internal.sendGMail({{0xb3cd52, 0x12}, {0xb2b38e, 0x4}, {0xb4e56a, 0x29}, {0xc000610000, 0x8a66}})
        /home/joss/user/mailprj/internal/gmail-api.go:149 +0x1b2
github.com/user/mailprj/internal.ListenForGMail.func1()
        /home/joss/user/mailprj/internal/gmail-api.go:114 +0xc6
created by github.com/user/mailprj/internal.ListenForGMail
        /home/joss/user/mailprj/internal/gmail-api.go:111 +0x25
exit status 2
```

Comment: I added the error I get

Comment: You need to get a token first, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756962/gmail-api-token-expired-how-to-get-new-one.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka, I did have a token but I did not pass it correctly in the options. I fixed it as in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not that obvious but easy to solve.
While initializing the `gmail.NewService()` I needed to pass the config parameter as option, just like the previous implementation of `gmail.New()` was using

So before was

```
client := getClient(config)
srv, err := gmail.New(client)
```

And now it is

```
client := getClient(config)
ctx := context.Background()
srv, err := gmail.NewService(
    ctx,
    option.WithHTTPClient(client),
)
```

In more context of the Gmail API implementation for Go, you need to take all the functions used at

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go or

https://github.com/googleworkspace/go-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/quickstart.go

and put them in your go file. These will generate both an AccessToken and the Credentials which, if you follow the guide correctly, you will need to save as a json file and reuse. credentials.json are used to update your AccessToken.

Now instead of using `gmail.New()`, the correct way is to use the function as shown above.

The entire sendGmail function is as follows

```
func sendGMail(m models.MailData) error {
    credentials := "../gmail_credentials.json"
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(credentials)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("unable to read credentials file:", err))
    }

    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.GmailSendScope)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("unable to parse credentials file config:", err))
    }

    client := getClient(config)
    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := gmail.NewService(
        ctx,
        option.WithHTTPClient(client),
        option.WithScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to retrieve gmail client: %s", err)
    }

    // Create message
    gMessage := ComposeMessage(m)

    if err := doSend(gMessage, srv); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not send mail: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Email sent")

    return nil
}
```